# why this error? Use of uninitialized value in join or string at

Tags: linux, perl, shell

When I run this script :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

my @header = split ' ', <>;
my $last = q();
my @keep;
for my $i (0 .. $#header) {
    my ($prefix) = $header[$i] =~ /(.*)\./;
    if ($prefix eq $last) {
        push @keep, $i + 1;
    }
    $last = $prefix;
}
unshift @header, q();
say join "\t", @header[@keep];

while (<>) {
    my @columns = split;
    say join "\t", @columns[@keep];
}
```

Then I get this error:

```
Use of uninitialized value in join or string at./first.perl line 21, <> line 3986.
```

Can you guide me how I can get ride out of this error? 
should I change something n may data file? Because when run this script in a small data file, I do not get error. But when I run it is my real data file, I get error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least one of the elements of the array slice `@columns[@keep]` is `undef`

You probably have a blank line at the end of your file. Take a look at line 3986 of your input file

I suggest you change your final loop to this, which skips lines that don't contain a non-space character

```
while (<>) {
    next unless /\S/;

    my @columns = split;

    if ( $keep[-1] > $#columns ) {
        warn "Malformed data at input file line $.\n";
        next;
    }

    say join "\t", @columns[@keep];
}
```

Comment: I did what you said, again I get eactly same error as before; uninitialized value in join or string at ./firstt.perl line 22, <> line 3986.
Use of uninitialized value in join or string at ./firstt.perl line 22, <> line 3986. do you have another suggestion?

Comment: @zara - To emphasize Borodin's diagnosis, the problem is line 3986 of your data file. If the suggested code change didn't resolve the warning, then that line must not be completely blank, but it apparently doesn't contain data for any of the fields found in `@keep`.

Comment: @zara: Please confirm that your problem has been solved. You must look at line 3986 of your data file to see the problem. If you need further help then you should ask a new question

Comment: @zara: Please don't just walk away when your issue has been resolved. ***A solution to your question is useful primarily so that it can help others with a similar problem.*** Since you have said that my code which just skips empty lines didn't help you at all, please elaborate on exactly what was wrong and how it was resolved

Comment: @Borodin thank you for your explanation. As you explained in your answer, there was some blank points in the last line of my data file. in fact half part of the last line was empty. But when I  create my data file correctly, the black points just gone and my problem resolved. But as long as blank points was existing in last line your solution was not useful.

Comment: @Borodin the reason that I ticket your answer, was that you mentioned in your answer, that there is blank point in last line which was correct.

Comment: @zara: It sounds like your data file had been truncated. I have modified my answer so that it produces a *Malformed data* warning message if there are insufficient columns in a line of data to match the indexes in `@keep`. I could not have written that without your additional information. Thank you. Please remember that the primary purpose of a Stack Overflow page is to help other people who have a similar problem. I realise that it is tempting to abandon your question once you have found a solution for yourself, but please think of it as a Wikipedia page that must be as accurate as possible